# Elixir's module attributes in Phoenix production

Tags: module, elixir, phoenix-framework

As far as I know module attributes evaluated during compilation time. I was trying to follow this [post](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/mocking-api-s-with-elixir) about mocking API in Elixir:

```
defmodule Example.User do

  @github_api Application.get_env(:example, :github_api)

  def get(username) when is_binary(username) do
    @github_api.make_request(:get, "/users/#{username}")
  end
end
```

And I'm wondering if that's gonna work in production at all. As far as I understand when this module is compiled there's no access to the Application. So my question is: can I use module attributes to store some config values that come from `Application.get_env`?

Comment: I believe you can and you should

Comment: Yes, you can and there's nothing wrong with it. But the value of `github_api` must be available to your application at compile-time. If you've already specified it in your env files, it should work without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can. As long as the application was compiled using `MIX_ENV` specified to environment you want the application running under, and as long as that call evaluates to what you expect for that environment, it'll all work fine.

For a deeper look at how module attributes are affected by compilation for an almost identical case as what you've described, [take a look at this blog post here](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/elixir-module-attributes-alchemy-101-part-1.html).